# function with parameters equals function with more parameters

Tags: julia

I am new to `julia` and am struggling to find information on a specific function syntax.

I have this code:

```
a = 1;

function foo(x,y,a)
    return x+y+a;    
end

bar(x,y) = foo(x,y,a);

bar(1,2)
```

What does the `bar(x,y) = foo(x,y,a);` line mean and when is it useful?

Best regards.

Comment: Besides Mark's answer take a look at https://discourse.julialang.org/t/closures-pass-by-value-or-reference/71155

Answer (score 2):

The `bar(x,y) = foo(x,y,a);` line creates a new function which adds `x` and `y` with the global variable `a`

It would be useful in situations in which you are repeatedly running the `foo()` function with the same `a` variable, and you'd rather not have to pass it every time

The disadvantage would be that if your code gets long and/or complex, and you are reassigning global variables like `a`, your code becomes harder to debug!

Comment: Smell ai, or that people are now copying ai style

Comment: The latter, not the former 